# rails multistep form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wizard

id like to make a multistep form with rails using the `edit` and `update` actions. so i would like it to be like `step 1` of the form, and the user fills in his name, address, and phone number. then the user clicks `save and continue` and he then fills out his shipping address and then clicks `save and continue` and fills out his billing address. i saw ryan bates version, but its not what im looking for. i would like the order to be saved after the first step so if the user doesnt finish their form, i can call them and ask them what went wrong. can anyone refer me to a tutorial or give me an example of how to make an order form using the `edit` and `update` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically this means you'll need to put conditions on your model validations. Some subset of your validations should apply to each form page:

```
class User
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :street,      :if => :on_page_two?
  validates_presence_of :city,        :if => :on_page_two?
  validates_presence_of :postal_code, :if => :on_page_two?
  validates_presence_of :state,       :if => :on_page_two?
  validates_presence_of :country,     :if => :on_page_two?
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_and_conditions, :if => :on_page_three?

  def on_page_two?
    # whatever you need to determine the page number
  end

  def on_page_three?
    # whatever you need to determine the page number
  end
end
```

It's not pretty but I highly recommend a pattern like this. Anything more complicated and you'll need to rewrite it when your signup flow changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approches to this problem.

My particular prefered solution is to implement something like a "State Machine" in the model. This way, I can persist the progress of a, per example, a multistep form, without having to hasle with more actions than new/create and edit/update.

I'm currently working on a heavy long State Machine application using the [State Machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem for rails.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a great Railcast on creating multi-step wizard forms, which you can find [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked). It uses the Wicked gem.